# Синтаксис bash: Определение версии дистрибутива Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Пытаюсь установить приложение, но исполняемый скрипт определил, что `Debian 8.2` не соответсвует требованиям установке. Так ли оно на самом деле?

Вот часть исходника (определение версии Linux):

```
# Find out what flavor of Linux were running on.       Added NX075P30
if $( grep -i "SuSE " /proc/version 1>$NULL 2>&1) ; then # Its SuSE.

  MIN_REV=10                             # Minimum SuSE version.
  RELEASE_FILE=/etc/SuSE-release         # Path to the release info file.

  # Check the rev level by reading VERSION out of the release file.
  if SUSE_REV=$(grep -i VERSION $RELEASE_FILE 2>$NULL) ; then
  # Edit out anything but numbers.
  #SUSE_REV=$(echo $SUSE_REV | sed 's![A-Z,a-z,=,-,., ]!!g')
  # Translate out anything BUT digits, we just want the number(s).
  SUSE_REV=$(echo $SUSE_REV | tr -cd [:digit:] )
  # Check for the minimum rev.
  [ "$SUSE_REV" -lt $MIN_REV ] && {    # Must be at least MIN_REV.
  print "${WARN}Unsupported Linux version: SuSE $SUSE_REV.
  \r\t The $PRODNAME $NX_VER required minimum is: SuSE ${MIN_REV}." >&2 
  sleep 3
  }
  else # Couldnt find the file or couldnt get the version num.
  print "${WARN}Unable to determine SuSE Linux version.
  \r\t Could not find SuSE release file: $RELEASE_FILE
  \r\t or, could not get SuSE version number from file.
  \r\t The minimum required version is: SuSE ${MIN_REV}.
  \r\t $PRODNAME $NX_VER MAY not run on this machine. " >&2 
  sleep 3
  fi

  # Now find X11/app-defaults dir. It moved so check two known places.
  [ -d /usr/share/X11/app-defaults ] && {       # Ck New location.
  X11_DEFS_DIR=/usr/share/X11/app-defaults ;}
  : ${X11_DEFS_DIR:=/usr/lib/X11/app-defaults}  # Default to old location.

elif $( grep -i "RED HAT " /proc/version 1>$NULL 2>&1) ; then # Its Red Hat.
  # Not much to do here, just set X11_DEFS_DIR.
  X11_DEFS_DIR=/usr/share/X11/app-defaults     # X11 app-defaults dir.
else # Couldnt detect SuSE or Red Hat so give unsuppored message and quit.
  print "${ERR} Unrecognized or unsupported Linux." >&2 
  exit 1
fi

PATH=.:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/etc ; export PATH # Set the PATH
UGS_TMP=/tmp/ugs_tmp               # Define a stash area for old files.
PS_CMD="ps -ef"                    # ps command for this system.
DF_CMD="df -k"                     # df command for this system.
AWK_CMD=awk                        # awk command for this system.
TMP_DIR=/tmp                       # Tmp directory.
LPATH_VAR_NAME=LD_LIBRARY_PATH     # Library path var name. V160P14
alias -x pwd='pwd -L'              # Tweak Linux pwd to give logical pwd.
alias -x uncompress=gunzip         # On SuSE 10 must use gunzip. NX050P24
```

Насколько я понимаю, скрипт выполняет проверку соответствия дистрибутива из семейства [openSUSE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) (поправьте меня если ошибаюсь). По структуре каталогов, вроде как проблем не нахожу. Что касается условия, тот я не силен, и прошу помощи в определении:

```
grep -i "SuSE " /proc/version 1>$NULL 2>&1
```

Какая конструкция была бы верная, относительно дистрибутива Debian 8.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поиск нужно grep -i "debian" делать. А RELEASE_FILE , в дебианах по моему в /etc/issue лежит

Comment: я пробовал менять именование на `Dtbian`, но этого не достаточно. Вы не могли бы пояснить, что соответствует условию, что он ищет (номер или...)?

Comment: Example SUSE: `/proc/version` Linux version 2.6.27.56-0.1-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.3.2 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 141291] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP 2010-12-01 16:57:58 +0100

Answer (score 1):

> исполняемый скрипт оприделил, что Debian 8.2 не соответсвует требованиям установки. Так ли оно на самом деле?

да, так и есть. любая версия дистрибутива *debian* будет диагностирована как "Unrecognized or unsupported".

кстати, версию программы *linux* данный скрипт **не** проверяет.

> Какая конструкция была бы верная, относительно дистрибутива Debian 8.2?

насколько я понимаю, никакая: этот скрипт явно предназначен для запуска внутри установленных дистрибутивов *suse* или *redhat*.

---

если вам не важен конечный результат (работоспособность устанавливаемой программы), а важно лишь чтобы выполнение скрипта пошло дальше, то просто закомментируйте весь этот код с проверками, оставив вместо него строку:

```
X11_DEFS_DIR=/etc/X11/app-defaults
```

скрипт этот, скорее всего, потребует для выполнения *root-овых* привилегий, потому запускать его лучше на тестовой машине (например, виртуальной).

а ещё лучше: воспользоваться всё-таки тем дистрибутивом, на который ориентировался разработчик этого скрипта.

Comment: Это тасть скрипта [ug_install](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5ldtvjpsx2wjp9/ug_install?dl=0)
В нем выполняется проверка в `case` тип OS

Comment: @ViteDecorum , увы, я не понял, о чём это должно мне сказать.

Comment: Это к тому, что в скрипте выполняется не только соответствие дистрибутива но и тип системы.

Comment: @ViteDecorum , прекрасно. вы не согласны с тем, что приведённый вами скрипт предназначен для запуска лишь внутри установленных дистрибутивов *suse* или *redhat*?

Comment: Не согласен, есть примеры установки на Ubuntu, Mint и т.д. Нужно просто корректировать определения, или дописать дополнительное условие...

Comment: приведённый вами кусок скрипта прекратит работу в любом дистрибутиве, отличном от *suse* или *redhat*. если у вас есть примеры, так воспользуйтесь ими, а не этим скриптом.

Comment: Вы правы, но вопрос не об этом. В прочем, я разобрался в чем причина. Условие выполняется, если функция `grep` находит соответствие `Debian` в строке файла `/proc/version`

Comment: *Нужно просто корректировать определения, или дописать дополнительное условие* — если вам нужно, чтобы выполнение пошло дальше, но не важен резульат (работоспособность устанавливаемой программы), то просто закомментируйте все эти проверки.

Answer (score 0):

Для Debian, как для [LSB](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb)-совместимого дистрибутива, его версия находится в файле `/etc/lsb-relase` в формате ключ=значение. Так же есть утилита для получения данных оттуда `lsb_relase`.

Ещё для Debian и основанных на нём дистрибутивах разная информация о версии содержится в файлах `/etc/os-release` и `/etc/debian_version`.

См. так же [вопрос о определении версии Debian на unix-разделе сайта](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script).

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, в Debian директория `app-default` - это `/usr/share/applications/`, или что-то другое?

Comment: @ViteDecorum, я не знаю что такое `app-default`, `/usr/share/applications/` существует, в ней находятся ярлыки графических приложений для создания меню.

Comment: я имел ввиду директорию аналог `/etc/X11/app-defaults` в Debian. То есть, по назначению, это то же самое, или нечто другое?

Comment: Другое. В `/usr/share` находятся постоянные данные для пакетов, а в `/etc`   их общесистемные настройки.

Comment: Ошибся, путь такой: `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults`. Не могу найти определение данной директории, применительно к Debian. Переменная `X11_DEFS_DIR` используется в функции `Updt_resource_files`. Вы можете пояснить, директория `X11` является системной для общих файлов, или приминительно к драйверу `nvidia`?

Comment: Директория X11 -  общесистемная. Наберите `dpkg -S /etc/X11`, увидите большой список пакетов, к которым она относится.

Comment: Для `/usr/share/X11` список уже меньше, а `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults` у меня вообще нет. Назначение их совершенно разное, в `/etc` настройки, а в `/usr/share` постоянные данные, например шрифты, иконки, файлы описания интерфейса, скрипты и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, я так же не вижу директорию `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults`. Синтаксис `bash` для меня до конца не понятен. Скрипт инсталляции приложения использует данный путь, по этому я озадачен. С архитектурой Linux я совершенно не знаком. Прошу прощения, если задаю глупые вопросы.

Comment: Если скрипт собирается записать файлы в эту директорию, наверно стоит её создать, потому что программа будет потом искать свои файлы именно там. Было бы неплохо отследить все новые директории и файлы созданные скриптом и записать их в БД установленных пакетов, благо она в Дебиане в текстовом формате.

Comment: в скрипте выполняется проверка на наличие данной директории, и если она найдена, то записывается в переменную `X11_DEFS_DIR` для использования функцией `Updt_resource_files`. Разработчики не позаботились о создании директории `app-defaults`, потому что в `SUSE` данная директория имеется по умолчанию. Создать, конечно, можно, но не приведет это к сбою приложения.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
lsb_release -a > rlsnf
cat rlsnf
if ! grep -i debian rlsnf
then
echo "Debian NO"
else
echo "Debian YES"
fi
rm rlsnf
```

вместо **echo** выполнять то что нужно.